# Почему возникают проблемы с буфером обмена, если java запущена как сервис?

Tags: java, windows, javafx

Javafx приложение запущено в Windows с наивысшими правами от имени пользователя System (как сервис)  на рабочем столе одного из обычных пользователей. Наблюдаю следующее проведение, если скопировать текст из браузера, то при попытке вставки в мое java приложение, оно не видет, что в буфере что-то есть. Если я копирую текст из адресной строки или любого другого места, где именно текст, то все работает.

Если это же приложение запустить в обычном режиме, то скопированный форматированный тест из браузера, как и ожидается, выставляется в текстовые поля приложения обычным текстом.

Comment: Если я через Toolkit запрашиваю типы данных в буфере, то получаю DataObject и cf0